# Starting thread causing abort()

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm trying to create a thread with the regular c++11 threads.
I have an object called NetworkManager that creates a thread of one of its methods in its constructor like this:

```
void NetworkManager()
{
    // Raknet setup here...
    std::thread networkUpdate(&NetworkManager::update, this);

    // Set timers
    playerDataTimer.start();
    playerDataTimer.pause();

    Logger::log("NetworkManager constructor ended");
}
```

The update method handles the messages coming on from other clients via the RakNet library like here: [Link](http://www.jenkinssoftware.com/raknet/manual/tutorialsample3.html)

I did the same thing as in the example where it's encapsulated in a while loop that keeps going forever.

When I try to create this thread in the constructor however I get an abort() message (the application crashes) and I can't figure out why this is. All objects that are used in the thread are setup before the loop starts so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Use a debugger to find out *where* the abort happens (in your code).

Comment: It happens right after the constructor ends. If I remove the thread creation it doesn't abort

Comment: I edited the code in the question. No, is the answer, it isn't the last line. I'm using these calls in other parts of the application as well and they seem to work just fine though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `std::thread` object you're creating gets destroyed at the end of your constructor since it is a local variable. If the [destructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread) of a `std::thread` is called while the thread is joinable (like it is in your example), `std::terminate` is called.

You must keep that thread object as a member of your class, or store it somewhere else, or detach the thread. (Or join with it in your constructor, but that doesn't sound like it would do what you want.)

Comment: Well, that was just very stupid on my end. No idea how I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Comment: Do you happen to know the rationale for this behaviour? I would have detached the thread instead if I had implemented `std::thread`...

Comment: I don't know the rationale, but read that it was debated a lot. There's no right choice. `join` or `detach` are both problematic - you'd expect detach but other people might expect join  (`std::async` does a join... which was also a problematic decision). Forcing the developer to be explicit doesn't seem like such a bad choice to me.

Answer (score 1):

Your app terminates because the `std::thread` is destructed without being `.detach`ed or `.join`ed.

```
~thread();
Destroys the thread object.
If *this has an associated thread (joinable() == true), std::terminate() is called.
```